# A cell containing a range of values and making calculations with that range

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, re2

Is it possible to have a range of values in a cell so that Sheets understands it when calculating something?

Here's an example of the **desired output**:

```
     A      B         C
1    Value  Share     Total sum
2    100.00 90-110%   90-110
```

Here, Total sum (C2) = A2 * B2 (so 100 * 90-110%), giving a range of 90-110.

However, I don't know how to insert this range of values into a cell without Sheets saying `#VALUE!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to do it like this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE((A2*REGEXEXTRACT(B2, "\d+")%)&"-"&
               A2*REGEXEXTRACT(B2, "-(\d+%)"), "\.$", )
```

[image: 0]

for decimals:

```
=REGEXREPLACE((A40*REGEXEXTRACT(B40, "\d+.\d+|\d+")%)&"-"&
               A40*REGEXEXTRACT(B40, "-(\d+.\d+%)|-(\d+%)"), "\.$", )
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you, however, this method seems to often skip the last number. For example, 500 * 90-110% = 450-55, and 10 * 90-110% = 9-1. 100 * 50-150% = 50-15. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Thank you very much @player0. I was surprised there's no "easy way" to do this, but this one works perfectly too.

Comment: Do you happen to know if it would be possible to also make a (line/area) chart using these value ranges, so that the chart would show the range of values? I'm assuming these "90-110" type values can't be used as such as they're just plaintext, but is there a way to do this in Sheets?

Comment: only with helping columns coz "90-110" is not numeric value but a text string so you need to split it